# Почему не работает else в условии if?

Tags: javascript, if

Также при вводе значений, отличных от заданных в `if` и `else if`, выполняется условие `else if`.

```
var q1 = prompt ("1");
if ((q1 == "q") || (q1 == "w") || (q1 == "e")) {
  alert ("qwe");
} else if ((q1 == "f") || (q1 == "g") || (q1 = "h")) {
  alert ("fgh");
} else {
  alert ("sdgw");
}
```

Comment: Опечатка в `(q1 = "h")` - не хватает одного `=`.

Comment: Чтобы избежать таких глупых ошибок рекомендуется сначала писать значение, с которым производится сравнение, а потом имя переменной ( "h" == q1). Тогда сразу вылезет предупреждение.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Эникейщик, такой код неприятно читать. Не надо такое советовать!

Comment: @Эникейщик, Зависит от вкуса или принятого StyleGuide.

Comment: @Bharata, не надо дописывать в заголовке _[решение найдено]_ и подобное, для этого есть зеленая галочка на ответе, и плашки при закрытии.